# Insert from MS SQL to Lotus Notes using NotesSQL drive

Tags: sql-server, unicode, ssis, lotus-notes, dts

I am trying to sync up a SQL Server table with a Lotus Notes database. I have set up the NotesSQL ODBC driver and have been able to insert, update and select from the notes database form using the ActiveX Script Task in DTS. Everything works well until I try to insert Chinese characters into Text field in the notes database. After insertion, all I got are ??? characters.

So my question is how do you insert unicode into notes database using the ODBC driver? i have tried something like this (where NotesForm is a form from notes): 
Insert NotesForm (UnicodeField, Field2) VALUES (N'some unicode', 'normal field')

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you testing whether you can read the Unicode characters in the Notes client at all?  Where are you seeing the ??? characters - in the Notes client, from the web view of the .NSF?  

You might want to consider pulling the data from the other side using Lotuscript ODBC connections to SQL.  It's going to be a lot better implementation of ODBC than the crazy Notes SQL driver.

If that's not going to work for you, try using the Notes API and directly updating documents.  Tons of docs over on http://notes.net.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the volume of data you are looking at you might be better of with a web service. It is fairly easy to create a CRUD service in Domino. Head over to my blog to read [Part1](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-6U22ST) and [Part2](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-6XK72K) how to do that. Webservices use UTF-8 and shouldn't be plagued by charset troubles.

Just to be sure: You used the latest NotesSQL (8.0)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about your issue, but have you tried to import data through SSIS? I guess there might be an option or so to perform your task.

Perhaps could simply change the encoding of your Notes field. I can't tell you more, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put some Chinese characters into Notes, then read them using NotesSQL driver and then try to figure out what encoding You are really using.